# How to sign another app in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-app-signing

I've written an application and published it on the Google Play store, now another programmer write it again and wants me to share my sign key file with them.

Is there any way that I can get apk file from them and sign it by myself and send it to them?

Comment: You can ask for his entire project. Import it into your Android Studio, test run it, sign and publish the new apk from your system to Google Play Console. Sharing your sign key file would need you to share the password for it to sign the apk, which is not a good idea.

Comment: Generally you should not use your key for publishing applications which belong to someone else... Next time create separate key, which you will give to the owner. If you don' t use this key for other apps, just give him... otherwise, import the project to AS and do the publishing by yourself

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad situation because

- Passing your keys is bad
- Signing the apk everytime they want to deploy is bad

Solving it needs some more finnese. You can use the Google Play auto sigin process and the transfer app from Google Play as well.

1. Go to your Google Play account and selecet the app
2. Opt-in and follow the process for the Google Play signing
3. Update the app to see how the Google Play process actually work
4. Transfer the app to the other developer account
5. The other developer will have to contact support to allow a new .jks file

Google Signing: You still need a .jks file, but if is lost or compromised you can contact support to allow a new .jks file

Transfer App: Both have to fill some forms here is more info

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en

I think this is better because the other developer will be able to create a new .jks file and will be responsible for contacting support